# Did Prophet Muhammad (SAWS) recite Darood-e-Ibrahim during the salah?

Tags: salat, source-identification, prophet-muhammad, darood

Did Prophet Muhammad (SAWS) recited *Darood-e-Ibrahim* in salah?

Is there any authentic reference stating that Prophet Muhammad (SAWS) recited *Darood* in salah?

Comment: What is Darood-e-Ibrahim?

Comment: [darood-e-ibrahim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durood#Durood-e-Ibrahimi) as I known in my childhood, it must say for all of people, and prophet should say it too.

Comment: unfortunately i could not find english translations of these hadiths

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet (pbuh) stated that all companions do Salat (prayer) as I do (صلوا کما رأیتمونی أصلی ).

There are some hadiths prove that the Prophet blessed himself as the companions did in Salat:

> قالت عایشه (رضی الله عنه ): کنا نعد لرسول الله صلی الله علیه وسلم
> سواکه و طهوره، فیبعثه الله فیما شاء أن یبعثه من اللیل، فیتسوک و یتوضا،
> ثم یصلی تسع رکعات لایجلس فیهن إلا عند الثامنة، فیدعو ربه و **یصلی علی
> نبیه**، ثم ینهض و لا یسلم، ثم یصلی التاسعة، فیقعد، ثم یحمد ربه و یصلی
> علی نبیه صلی الله علیه وسلم و یدعو، ثم یسلم....) صحیح مسلم
>
> [Similar Version](http://sunnah.com/nasai/20/123) and in [sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/208)
>
> عن عبد الله عن النبی صلی الله علیه وسلم قال فی التشهد التحیات لله
> والصلوات والطیبات السلام علیک أیها النبی ورحمة الله وبرکاته السلام
> علینا وعلی عباد الله الصالحین أشهد أن لا إله إلا الله وأشهد أن محمدا
> عبده ورسوله " سنن النسایی
>
> [Similar Version](http://sunnah.com/nasai/12/136)
>
> روی کعب بن عجره : صلی رسول الله فی صلاته :اللهمّ صلّ علی محمّد و آل
> محمّد کما صلّیت علی ابراهیم و آل ابراهیم انّک حمیدٌ مجید. بحارالأنوار،
> ج82 ، ص 279
>
> ---

Comment: stating in English which book you got this from and who narrated it,,,  would help..... a lot, and try your level best to translate the main words in your own words in English until u get a perfect trnslation

Answer (score 0):

As referenced by the asker, "*Darood-e-Ibrahim*" is the Persian of "*as-Salaah al-Ibraaheemiyyah*" in Arabic.

One of the many forms of it, which is narrated in this following quote by al-Bukhaari, says: (translated to English)

> O Allaah, send prayers upon Muhammad and upon the family of Muhammad, as You sent prayers upon Ibraaheem and upon the family of Ibraaheem; You are indeed Worthy of Praise, Full of Glory. O Allaah, send blessings upon Muhammad and upon the family of Muhammad as You sent blessings upon Ibraaheem and upon the family of Ibraaheem; You are indeed Worthy of Praise, Full of Glory.

There are many Hadiths stating that the prophet told his companions to say it in the prayer (i.e. in Salah), and state the actual words of it. But, if you are looking only for a reference stating that the prophet himself said it, then the only book I found was: "*Tuhfat al-Muhtaj ila Adillati al-Minhaj*" by Ibnu al-Mulaqqan.

It says that Aisha (wife of the prophet, peace be upon them) was asked about the prophet's Witr Prayer , and she explained how he prays to Allah in this Salah, until she said: "Then, he sends prayers upon the prophet of Allah…".